# How to join 4 tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

I just started using SQL and I need some help. I have 4 tables in a database. All four are connected with each other. I need to find the amount of unique transactions but can't seem to find it.

**Transactions**

- transaction_id pk
- name

**Partyinvolved**

- transaction.id pk
- partyinvolved.id
- type (buyer, seller)

**PartyCompany**

- partyinvolved.id
- Partycompany.id

**Companies**

- PartyCompany.id pk
- sector

pk = primary key

The transaction is unique if the conditions are met. 
I only need a certain sector out of Companies, this is condition1. Condition2 is a condition inside table Partyinvolved but we first need to execute condition1. I know the conditions but do not know where to put them.

```
SELECT *
FROM group
INNER JOIN groupB ON groupB.group_id = group.id
INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = groupB.company_id
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 ;
```

I want to output the amount of unique transactions with the name.

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: yeah my bad, my first time posting

Comment: You can't have two tables with the name `group`.

Comment: Make it easy and possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: the SQL shows group, groupb and companies.  no purchases.  the tables listed show group twice, but no companies.  Rephrase teh question and show the PK FK relationships between the tables.  Seems odd that `Table group -purchase.id pk -groupB.id` exists... purchase.ID is the PK and it ties to groupB.ID?...

Comment: I want to output the name of purchaser with the purchase id so I can count how many purchases a certain purchaser has made... What table contains the name of the purchaser?  What's the cardinality between the tables? as it stands you count may be artifically inflated.

Comment: ok guys give me one minute ill update the tables. I only listed the columns which I thought I needed for the join clause.

Comment: Your latest update is not helping at all. Your column names in your query don't match what you state the names are in the table. You need to provide table definitions (create table statements), sample data (insert statements) as well as the desired output for the sample data provided. What is a "unique transaction" here?

Comment: as far as "I don't know where to put the conditions" the best place is within the ON clause of the join itself and where only for your first/anchor table

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you are asking as your table definitions look like your hinting at column meanings more than names such as `partycompany.id` you are probably meaning the column that stores the relationship to `PartyCompany` column `Id`......

Anyway, If I follow that logic and I look at your questions about wanting to know where to limit the recordsets during the join.  You could do it in `Where` clause because you are using an `Inner Join` and it wont mess you your results, but the same would not be true if you were to use an `outer join`.  Plus for optimization it is typically best to add the limiter to the `ON` condition of the join.

I am also a bit lost as to what exactly you want e.g. a count of transactions or the actual transactions associated with a particular sector for instance.  Anyway, either should be able to be derived from a basic query structure like:

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    Companies co
    INNER JOIN PartyCompancy pco
    ON co.PartyCompanyId = pco.PartyCompanyId
    INNER JOIN PartyInvolved pinv
    ON pco.PartyInvolvedId = pinv.PartyInvolvedId
    AND pinv.[type] = 'buyer'
    INNER JOIN Transactions t
    ON ping.TransactionId = t.TransactionId
WHERE
    co.sector = 'some sector'
```